# Last Quarter End-Date in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark, datetime, apache-spark-sql

I have a SQL-Server query that calculates the **last quarter End-date**. Now, I need to convert this query into a `Spark-SQL` query.

The `Sql-Server` query and some sample examples are:

```
select dateadd(dd, -1, dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, cast('2020-09-09' AS DATE)), 0)) as end_dt
```

Output: `2020-06-30`

To calculate the same for another (`2021-01-10`) date:

```
select dateadd(dd, -1, dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, cast('2021-01-10' AS DATE)), 0)) as end_dt
```

Output: `2020-12-31`

**Question**: How can I **implement** the same in **Spark SQL query** (v2.4) ? How do I calculate the **last day** of the **previous** quarter as per the `SQL-Server` examples above and the required output below ?

```
input_date | end_date
------------------------
2020-01-21 | 2019-12-31
2020-02-06 | 2019-12-31
2020-04-15 | 2020-03-31
2020-07-10 | 2020-06-30
2020-10-20 | 2020-09-30
2021-02-04 | 2020-12-31
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date_trunc()`:

```
select date_add(
    date_trunc(cast('2020-09-09' as date), 'quarter'), 
    -1
) as end_dt
```

Comment: it is returning a Null value

Comment: putting the `quarter` specifier at the beginning seems to solve the problem - `select date_add(
    date_trunc('quarter', cast('2020-09-09' as date)), -1
) as end_dt`

Answer (score 0):

To find immediate quarter end date for the given date.

```
select add_months(last_day(date_trunc('quarter',to_timestamp('2020-12-03','yyyy-MM-dd'))),2) as end_dt
```

to find immediate year end date for the given date.

```
select add_months(last_day(date_trunc('year',to_timestamp('2020-06-03','yyyy-MM-dd'))),11) as end_dt
```

to find immediate bi-annual end date for the given date.

```
select case when quarter(to_timestamp('2020-11-03','yyyy-MM-dd')) >=3 then 
add_months(last_day(date_trunc('year',to_timestamp('2020-11-03','yyyy-MM-dd'))),11) 
          when quarter(to_timestamp('2020-11-03','yyyy-MM-dd')) < 3 then 
add_months(last_day(date_trunc('year',to_timestamp('2020-11-03','yyyy-MM-dd'))),5)
          end as end_dt
```